# How can I solve validation error in my json data?

Tags: json

For single json data, showing valid

```
{"Title": "Internet Cafe Simulator Mod APK 1.4", "Name": "Internet Cafe Simulator", "Compatible with": "4.1", "Latest version": "1.4", "Developer": "Cocopo", "Google play link": " com.CheesecakeDev.InternetCafeSimulator", "Price": "Free", "Size": "41M", "MOD": "Yes", "Category": " Simulation", "Picture_url": "https://techbigs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/internet-cafe-simulator-687.png", "Description": "DESCRIPTION pment for your caf\u00e9. then download the unlimited money mod for Internet Cafe Simulator and go about building the caf\u00e9 of your dreams."}
```

But multipule json data showing validation error....

```
{
    {"Title": "Internet Cafe Simulator Mod APK 1.4", "Name": "Internet Cafe Simulator", "Compatible with": "4.1", "Latest version": "1.4", "Developer": "Cocopo", "Google play link": " com.CheesecakeDev.InternetCafeSimulator", "Price": "Free", "Size": "41M", "MOD": "Yes", "Category": " Simulation", "Picture_url": "https://techbigs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/internet-cafe-simulator-687.png", "Description": "DESCRIPTION pment for your caf\u00e9. then download the unlimited money mod for Internet Cafe Simulator and go about building the caf\u00e9 of your dreams."},

    {"Title": "Internet Cafe Simulator Mod APK 1.4", "Name": "Internet Cafe Simulator", "Compatible with": "4.1", "Latest version": "1.4", "Developer": "Cocopo", "Google play link": " com.CheesecakeDev.InternetCafeSimulator", "Price": "Free", "Size": "41M", "MOD": "Yes", "Category": " Simulation", "Picture_url": "https://techbigs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/internet-cafe-simulator-687.png", "Description": "DESCRIPTION Internet Cafe without having to go through the long process of building it from the bottom up"},

    {"Title": "Internet Cafe Simulator Mod APK 1.4", "Name": "Internet Cafe Simulator", "Compatible with": "4.1", "Latest version": "1.4", "Developer": "Cocopo", "Google play link": " com.CheesecakeDev.InternetCafeSimulator", "Price": "Free", "Size": "41M", "MOD": "Yes", "Category": " Simulation", "Picture_url": "https://techbigs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/internet-cafe-simulator-687.png", "Description": "DESCRIPTION ther local businesses to build up a network and acquire more to build your dream building the caf\u00e9 of your dreams."}
}
```

what can i do now? Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you've wrapped the objects inside an outer object, but you haven't given those objects property names, so they're not identifiable.

There are two possible solutions:

1) Maybe you intended to create an array (i.e. a list), rather than an object? In that case, you don't need to name each item, instead it will get a numeric index automatically (and invisibly). Arrays are declared using square brackets (`[ ... ]`) instead of curly brackets (`{ ... }`).

```
[
    {
        "Title": "Internet Cafe Simulator Mod APK 1.4",
        "Name": "Internet Cafe Simulator",
        "Compatible with": "4.1",
        "Latest version": "1.4",
        "Developer": "Cocopo",
        "Google play link": " com.CheesecakeDev.InternetCafeSimulator",
        "Price": "Free",
        "Size": "41M",
        "MOD": "Yes",
        "Category": " Simulation",
        "Picture_url": "https://techbigs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/internet-cafe-simulator-687.png",
        "Description": "DESCRIPTION pment for your caf\u00e9. then download the unlimited money mod for Internet Cafe Simulator and go about building the caf\u00e9 of your dreams."
    },

    {
        "Title": "Internet Cafe Simulator Mod APK 1.4",
        "Name": "Internet Cafe Simulator",
        "Compatible with": "4.1",
        "Latest version": "1.4",
        "Developer": "Cocopo",
        "Google play link": " com.CheesecakeDev.InternetCafeSimulator",
        "Price": "Free",
        "Size": "41M",
        "MOD": "Yes",
        "Category": " Simulation",
        "Picture_url": "https://techbigs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/internet-cafe-simulator-687.png",
        "Description": "DESCRIPTION Internet Cafe without having to go through the long process of building it from the bottom up"
    },

    {
        "Title": "Internet Cafe Simulator Mod APK 1.4",
        "Name": "Internet Cafe Simulator",
        "Compatible with": "4.1",
        "Latest version": "1.4",
        "Developer": "Cocopo",
        "Google play link": " com.CheesecakeDev.InternetCafeSimulator",
        "Price": "Free",
        "Size": "41M",
        "MOD": "Yes",
        "Category": " Simulation",
        "Picture_url": "https://techbigs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/internet-cafe-simulator-687.png",
        "Description": "DESCRIPTION ther local businesses to build up a network and acquire more to build your dream building the caf\u00e9 of your dreams."
    }
]
```

2) Give each property a name. This seems, on the face of it, like a less likely or useful structure:

```
{
    "item1": {
        "Title": "Internet Cafe Simulator Mod APK 1.4",
        "Name": "Internet Cafe Simulator",
        "Compatible with": "4.1",
        "Latest version": "1.4",
        "Developer": "Cocopo",
        "Google play link": " com.CheesecakeDev.InternetCafeSimulator",
        "Price": "Free",
        "Size": "41M",
        "MOD": "Yes",
        "Category": " Simulation",
        "Picture_url": "https://techbigs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/internet-cafe-simulator-687.png",
        "Description": "DESCRIPTION pment for your caf\u00e9. then download the unlimited money mod for Internet Cafe Simulator and go about building the caf\u00e9 of your dreams."
    },

    "item2": {
        "Title": "Internet Cafe Simulator Mod APK 1.4",
        "Name": "Internet Cafe Simulator",
        "Compatible with": "4.1",
        "Latest version": "1.4",
        "Developer": "Cocopo",
        "Google play link": " com.CheesecakeDev.InternetCafeSimulator",
        "Price": "Free",
        "Size": "41M",
        "MOD": "Yes",
        "Category": " Simulation",
        "Picture_url": "https://techbigs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/internet-cafe-simulator-687.png",
        "Description": "DESCRIPTION Internet Cafe without having to go through the long process of building it from the bottom up"
    },

    "item3": {
        "Title": "Internet Cafe Simulator Mod APK 1.4",
        "Name": "Internet Cafe Simulator",
        "Compatible with": "4.1",
        "Latest version": "1.4",
        "Developer": "Cocopo",
        "Google play link": " com.CheesecakeDev.InternetCafeSimulator",
        "Price": "Free",
        "Size": "41M",
        "MOD": "Yes",
        "Category": " Simulation",
        "Picture_url": "https://techbigs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/internet-cafe-simulator-687.png",
        "Description": "DESCRIPTION ther local businesses to build up a network and acquire more to build your dream building the caf\u00e9 of your dreams."
    }
}
```

As a general point, make sure you understand the difference between arrays and objects, and that all properties of objects must have a name.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't valid JSON - you either need an array of objects or else named properties. i.e.

An array of objects - notice that the root element is an array `[]` not an object `{}`

```
   [{
        "Title": "Internet Cafe Simulator Mod APK 1.4",
        "Name": "Internet Cafe Simulator",
        "Compatible with": "4.1",
        "Latest version": "1.4",
        "Developer": "Cocopo",
        "Google play link": " com.CheesecakeDev.InternetCafeSimulator",
        "Price": "Free",
        "Size": "41M",
        "MOD": "Yes",
        "Category": " Simulation",
        "Picture_url": "https://techbigs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/internet-cafe-simulator-687.png",
        "Description": "DESCRIPTION pment for your caf\u00e9. then download the unlimited money mod for Internet Cafe Simulator and go about building the caf\u00e9 of your dreams."
    },

    {
        "Title": "Internet Cafe Simulator Mod APK 1.4",
        "Name": "Internet Cafe Simulator",
        "Compatible with": "4.1",
        "Latest version": "1.4",
        "Developer": "Cocopo",
        "Google play link": " com.CheesecakeDev.InternetCafeSimulator",
        "Price": "Free",
        "Size": "41M",
        "MOD": "Yes",
        "Category": " Simulation",
        "Picture_url": "https://techbigs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/internet-cafe-simulator-687.png",
        "Description": "DESCRIPTION Internet Cafe without having to go through the long process of building it from the bottom up"
    },

    {
        "Title": "Internet Cafe Simulator Mod APK 1.4",
        "Name": "Internet Cafe Simulator",
        "Compatible with": "4.1",
        "Latest version": "1.4",
        "Developer": "Cocopo",
        "Google play link": " com.CheesecakeDev.InternetCafeSimulator",
        "Price": "Free",
        "Size": "41M",
        "MOD": "Yes",
        "Category": " Simulation",
        "Picture_url": "https://techbigs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/internet-cafe-simulator-687.png",
        "Description": "DESCRIPTION ther local businesses to build up a network and acquire more to build your dream building the caf\u00e9 of your dreams."
    }]
```

Or named properties - notice that the root element is still an object `{}` but that each subobject is a named property of it `"foo": {}`

```
{
    "item1": {
        "Title": "Internet Cafe Simulator Mod APK 1.4",
        "Name": "Internet Cafe Simulator",
        "Compatible with": "4.1",
        "Latest version": "1.4",
        "Developer": "Cocopo",
        "Google play link": " com.CheesecakeDev.InternetCafeSimulator",
        "Price": "Free",
        "Size": "41M",
        "MOD": "Yes",
        "Category": " Simulation",
        "Picture_url": "https://techbigs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/internet-cafe-simulator-687.png",
        "Description": "DESCRIPTION pment for your caf\u00e9. then download the unlimited money mod for Internet Cafe Simulator and go about building the caf\u00e9 of your dreams."
    },

    "item2": {
        "Title": "Internet Cafe Simulator Mod APK 1.4",
        "Name": "Internet Cafe Simulator",
        "Compatible with": "4.1",
        "Latest version": "1.4",
        "Developer": "Cocopo",
        "Google play link": " com.CheesecakeDev.InternetCafeSimulator",
        "Price": "Free",
        "Size": "41M",
        "MOD": "Yes",
        "Category": " Simulation",
        "Picture_url": "https://techbigs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/internet-cafe-simulator-687.png",
        "Description": "DESCRIPTION Internet Cafe without having to go through the long process of building it from the bottom up"
    },

    "item3": {
        "Title": "Internet Cafe Simulator Mod APK 1.4",
        "Name": "Internet Cafe Simulator",
        "Compatible with": "4.1",
        "Latest version": "1.4",
        "Developer": "Cocopo",
        "Google play link": " com.CheesecakeDev.InternetCafeSimulator",
        "Price": "Free",
        "Size": "41M",
        "MOD": "Yes",
        "Category": " Simulation",
        "Picture_url": "https://techbigs.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/internet-cafe-simulator-687.png",
        "Description": "DESCRIPTION ther local businesses to build up a network and acquire more to build your dream building the caf\u00e9 of your dreams."
    }
}
```